# Asymptotic behavior of a function?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, definition

I am dealing with some elementary issues on asymptotic behavior(?) of some simple $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ functions.
For example, for a function like $f(t)=e^{-t}\sin t$, we all know that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t) = \lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-t}\sin t = 0,
\end{equation}
so that we can simply write $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t) = 0$. However, for functions like
\begin{equation}
g(t) = e^{-t}\sin t+\cos t,
\end{equation}
it's obvious that $g(t)$ asymptotically approaches to $\cos t$ as $t\to\infty$, but conventionally we don't use notations as $\lim_{t\to\infty}g(t)=\cos t$. I've been trying to find stuffs like this, but so far haven't quite seen any. So here comes my questions:

1. What can we call such '$\cos t$' in a relationship with $g(t)=e^{-t}\sin t+\cos t$? is it likely to introduce such 'asymptotic behavior operator's, for example, \tilde; like $\widetilde{g}(t)= \cos t$?
2. If there are rigorous definitions for such '$\cos t$', then are there theories for the properties of such 'asymptotic behavior operator's? For example, conditions for $\frac{d}{dt}\widetilde{f} =\widetilde{\frac{d}{dt}f}$, or $\widetilde{f+g} = \widetilde{f}+\widetilde{g}$,... etc.

I would like to express my gratitude to someone who can give a clear answer to this sloppy question. Thanks.

Comment: In terms of limits, you have to obey the limit laws. $cost$ cannot be an answer for a limit. But it is correct to say that as far as asymptotic behavior is concerned, $g(t)$ approaches the cosine curve

Comment: Please see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis. You could say $f(t)$ is asymptotically equivalent to $g(t)$.

Comment: Didn't knew it was a stuff from such field called asymptotic analysis. A lot helped, thank you very much.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations Probably all the notations you would like to use.